# Working from India in a US company

Tags: united-states, taxes, india, visa

I'm a new grad, working on a contract position in US for some time now and my contract has almost ended. I got an offer from another company (X), which is quite small (an LLC) but with better responsibilities. However, I'm planning to leave the US permanently in a few months and go back to India. This new company X has employees working from India also. Before I ask my manager,

1. I'd like to know how the process, the pay and taxes work if I have to leave the US, go back to India and work in the same position.
2. Also, I'm currently on OPT, do I need to have an H1B or anything of that sort to work for a US company from India?
3. Would it be W2 or 1099?

Comment: So you have 3 different and unrelated questions, two for this forum and one for expats@SE. Why not separate them so that people who can answer one - will?

Comment: @littleadv Sure, I didn't know about expats. I will separate them. Thanks for letting me know!

Answer (score 1):

> I'd like to know how the process, the pay and taxes work if I have to leave the US, go back to India and work in the same position.

You would need to pay Indian taxes. Its easier if you work as freelance contractor. If your company already has an office in India, then being employee of Indian company is also fine.

> Also, I'm currently on OPT, do I need to have an H1B or anything of that sort to work for a US company from India?

No

> Would it be W2 or 1099?

Again if you are doing it as freelance contract or employee of Indian company, none.